# Connecting AUNode Effects as type Send instead of Insert

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, core-audio

I have an audio graph with a chain of effects, but they are connected like Insert.

```
 AUGraphConnectNodeInput (processingGraph, mixerNode, 0, reverbNode1, 0);
 AUGraphConnectNodeInput (processingGraph, delayNode, 0, reverbNode1, 0);
 AUGraphConnectNodeInput (processingGraph, reverbNode, 0, iONode, 0);
```

But I need Reverb and Delay effects like send connections. 
This is the connection I Have:

mixerNode -> DelayNode -> ReverbNode -> iONode

And This is what I Need:

mixerNode ------------------> iONode

mixerNode -> ReverbNode --> iONode

mixerNode -> DelayNode ---> iONode

I saw an Sample, it's easy with AVFoundation like this...

```
[_engine connect:_player to:_reverb format:playerFormat];
[_engine connect:_reverb to:mainMixer fromBus:0 toBus:0 format:playerFormat];
[_engine connect:_distortion to:mainMixer fromBus:0 toBus:2 format:stereoFormat];
NSArray<AVAudioConnectionPoint *> *destinationNodes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[AVAudioConnectionPoint alloc] initWithNode:_engine.mainMixerNode bus:1],
                                                                                [[AVAudioConnectionPoint alloc] initWithNode:_distortion bus:0],
                                                                                  nil];

[_engine connect:_sampler toConnectionPoints:destinationNodes fromBus:0 format:stereoFormat];
```

My question is... How can I do this type of connections with AUNodes and my processing graph ?

Answer (score 1):

Well... if anyone needs it, the solutions seems to be kAudioUnitSubType_MultiSplitter